# iOS Homescreen Web Bookmark - Clicking home while the camera is open prevents the camera from opening again

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, ios16, ios17

I ran into quite a weird issue, wondering if anyone else has come across it/has a fix.

It only seems to be an issue affecting web pages saved to the home screen, I couldn't get this to repeat in either Safari or Chrome normally.

- A basic form saved to the home screen bookmark (tried with iOS 16.6 and 17.3.1)
- The form includes an image upload field
- Click the upload file to trigger the camera interface
- Click the Home button
- Relaunch bookmark

  - Shows the form, not the camera interface
- Can't relaunch the camera until the app is closed and relaunched.

As above I've tried to repeat the same issue in both Safari and Chrome

- Safari this just returns to the camera interface still open.
- Changing the default browser to Chrome does fix the issue (although it spawns multiple tabs of the same form), but it would be nice to fix this without relying on an external app.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question for Stackoverflowm since it's not a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in Safari. I'd file a bug with Apple via the Feedback Assistant and provide a nice clear repro case like you did here.